# Correct way to declare typedef enum in C?

Tags: c, enums, typedef

Is it a correct way to declare `enum` in C like so:

```
typedef enum
 {
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT = 0,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_CLOCKWISE90,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_COUNTERCLOCKWISE90, 
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_FLIP180,            
 } k4abt_sensor_orientation_t;
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
typedef enum
 {
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT = 0,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_CLOCKWISE90 = 1,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_COUNTERCLOCKWISE90 = 2, 
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_FLIP180 = 3,            
 } k4abt_sensor_orientation_t;
```

?

Comment: Do you need them to have particular values? If so, use the second form. This way if you reorder them or omit one it doesn't screw everything up numerically.

Comment: @blackmika The both declarations are equivalent.

Comment: <off-topic> I think FLIP180 is not the same as ROTATE...

Comment: Aside: I have found it useful to always end the list like with `K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_N` as for later value checking with `if (x >= 0 && x < K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_N) GoodToGo();`

Comment: @VladFeinstein not in our case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers)

> 3 The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants that
> have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.127) An
> enumerator with = defines its enumeration constant as the value of the
> constant expression. **If the first enumerator has no =, the value of
> its enumeration constant is 0. Each subsequent enumerator with no =
> defines its enumeration constant as the value of the constant
> expression obtained by adding 1 to the value of the previous
> enumeration constant.** (The use of enumerators with = may produce
> enumeration constants with values that duplicate other values in the
> same enumeration.) The enumerators of an enumeration are also known as
> its members.

So for example all these declarations are equivalent

```
typedef enum
 {
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_CLOCKWISE90,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_COUNTERCLOCKWISE90, 
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_FLIP180,            
 } k4abt_sensor_orientation_t;

typedef enum
 {
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT = 0,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_CLOCKWISE90,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_COUNTERCLOCKWISE90, 
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_FLIP180,            
 } k4abt_sensor_orientation_t;

typedef enum
 {
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_CLOCKWISE90 = 1,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_COUNTERCLOCKWISE90, 
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_FLIP180,            
 } k4abt_sensor_orientation_t;

typedef enum
 {
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_CLOCKWISE90,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_COUNTERCLOCKWISE90 = 2, 
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_FLIP180,            
 } k4abt_sensor_orientation_t;

typedef enum
 {
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_CLOCKWISE90,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_COUNTERCLOCKWISE90, 
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_FLIP180 = 3,            
 } k4abt_sensor_orientation_t;

typedef enum
 {
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT = 0,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_CLOCKWISE90 = 1,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_COUNTERCLOCKWISE90 = 2, 
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_FLIP180 = 3,            
 } k4abt_sensor_orientation_t;

typedef enum
 {
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_FLIP180 = 3,            
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_COUNTERCLOCKWISE90 = 2, 
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_CLOCKWISE90 = 1,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT = 0,        
 } k4abt_sensor_orientation_t;
```

However for more readability I would prefer this declaration

```
typedef enum
 {
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT = 0,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_CLOCKWISE90 = 1,        
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_COUNTERCLOCKWISE90 = 2, 
     K4ABT_SENSOR_ORIENTATION_FLIP180 = 3,            
 } k4abt_sensor_orientation_t;
```

especially when an enumeration contains many enumerators.

Comment: Another benefit of explicitly listing the enumerator values is to avoid silent problems when using source control and entries are added or removed

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow thanks for the comprehensive explanation!

Comment: @M.M explicity and avoiding silent problems matter!

Answer (score 3):

Both definitions are valid.

If an `enum` member doesn't have an explicit value set for it, its value is that of the prior member plus 1.  If the first member doesn't have an explicit value, its value is 0.